# Preventing duplicates when inserting data in gridview C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 tables, I need to copy the data of the parent table which is name (tblbenefit)" to another table (tbladdbenefit). So I need to retrieve and store the data of the parent table to the other table. And I also need to call it every time the form loads

the inserting part works, but the only problem I have is whenever the form loads, the table will insert along with the previous data I already displayed. So it will result in duplicate record whenever I open the form

So for example my parent table contains the values:
value1
value2

The values are inserting to the new table, but whenever i close the form and reopened it, it will insert it again. Resulting in the table looking like:

value1
value2
value1
value2

Any Help would be appriciated!

I have tried this code

```
 con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbladdbenefit(Benefit, Amount) Select from tblbenefit",             con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM tbladdbenefit";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Employee Info");
        tbladdbenefit.DataSource = ds;
        tbladdbenefit.DataMember = "Employee Info";
        con.Close();
```

```
`
```

Comment: Every time you open the mask, it inserts new rows to tbladdbenefit from tblbenefit
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbladdbenefit(Benefit, Amount) Select from tblbenefit",             con); 
You either need to empty table tbladdbenefit, or make sure that you only insert values that dont exist yet

Comment: any idea how to insert values not existing yet? I'm thinkin using INSERT IGNORE query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PrimaryKey and identify duplicates by comparing the PrimaryKey (GUID)

change

```
Insert into tbladdbenefit(Benefit, Amount) Select from tblbenefit
```

to

```
Insert into tbladdbenefit(Benefit, Amount, PrimaryKey) 
Select from tblbenefit 
where PrimaryKey not in (Select PrimaryKey from tbladdbenefit)
```

or an alternative approach (recommended)

```
 Delete From tbladdbenefit;
 Insert into tbladdbenefit(Benefit, Amount) Select from tblbenefit
```

Comment: thanks for the response! unfortunately i tried it and does not work. Created a primary key in my table but the same still occurs

Comment: adjusted the answer, you need the primary key in both tables.